# Medium size of icons

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm not sure why but when I try to set medium size (by passing "medium" alongside the other params in className) for icons, I get "unknown symbol" sign. I use semantic with react. It happens to whatever icon.

I use:

react: 16.6.3, 
semantic-ui-css: 2.4.1, 
semantic-ui-react: 0.83.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand in your question, I think you wrote it like this:
`<Icon name='users' className='medium' />` which is wrong.

The correct way is:
`<Icon name='users' size='large'/>`

Also, there's no 'medium'. The values are:

'mini', 'tiny', 'small', 'large', 'big', 'huge', and 'massive'

You can see its props here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/

Comment: Yeah you right, but what is weird is that other sizes works fine like that, except for the "medium" one. 

I use size param now. Thank you.

Comment: That is because technically those props generate those class names which are applied to the element. The benefit of using props is that you can get proptype warnings if you are using an enumerated value that is not supported in the styles. Like you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for middle is size='mid'

Comment: Although it is not mentioned in Semantic UI props, but it works :)

Comment: I'm using Semantic UI with React with the following versions -

`"semantic-ui-css": "^2.5.0",
 "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.4"`

`size="mid"` doesn't work.